# DC voltage step down

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator

I have 3.7 V samsung 2A43(ICR18650) battery cell extracted fromm laptop battery..  I want to  run trimmer machine motter which is 1.7 volt and 5 watt ..

what would i need

Comment: This ain't a "gimme design" service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of zero effort.

Comment: 38Ah pack better have OCP on each cell, judging by spelling of mah, you made a misteak;)

Comment: Yes I would kindly hlep you out, but I just don't know what "hlep" means.

Comment: I have 3.7 V samsung 2A43(ICR18650) battery cell extracted fromm laptop battery.. I want to run trimmer machine motter which is 1.7 volt and 5 watt ..

what would i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of chemistry do you have? Also are you sure it is 38000 mAH or is it 3800mAH ?

To step down from 3.7V you will need a step down voltage regulator. You will have to check the battery specs to see if it is capable of continuously supplying 2 to 3A.

Aby.